# Privileges vs Permissions

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

I might be missing a fundamental difference between the two, but shouldn't the tag [<kbd>Privileges</kbd>](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/privileges/info)  be a synonym of the tag [<kbd>Permissions</kbd>](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/permissions/info)?

(Click either tag above to view their info/about page)

Ironically the short description of each references the other word.  For example the short description of [permissions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/permissions) defines it as:

> Privileges granted to an account or role through the security
>   mechanism of an operating system, database manager or other system.

Whereas the short description of [privileges](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/privileges) defines it as:

> Permissions associated with, or required for, an operation on a
>   database system.

Those descriptions alone give credence in my mind that the terms are synonymous....

Personally I prefer the term `Permissions` to `Privileges`, but I would support either term as the primary.

Comment: It's probably worth reading http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46292/permission-vs-privilege which seems to be the definitive answer on the difference between the two. But for our intents and purposes they are virtually the same.

Comment: You are correct

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Yes.**

[privileges](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/privileges) (141 questions) should be a synonym of [permissions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/permissions) (381 questions).

The [privileges](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/privileges) tag should also be [merged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/263959/194636) into [permissions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/permissions).

I have added the synonym and performed the merge now.